# Reducing deployment time of a large image to AWS ECR from Azure Devops

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to push a docker image to AWS ECR via Azure Devops, but the image is 17gb when built. This results in the image taking extremely long to upload to ECR which is not ideal.

The large size is due to ML models that are part of the requirements for the code to run and currently there's not much that I can do about the size.

How do I get around the long upload time?

My current thoughts are:

- Patience(Just leave it and that's how it is)
- Make use of AWS CodeBuild so that the image generation happens on AWS and I hopefully don't have to wait for a long upload (I haven't used AWS CodeBuild before so not sure what the implications or shortfalls of the service are other than cost)

Comment: Moving it out of Azure and into AWS, and in the same region as the ECR repo, should speed things up considerably. It would be like the difference of copying something from your local computer to somewhere on the internet, and copying it from your local computer to another local computer on your home network. If you want to test this before spending the time converting everything to AWS CodeBuild, you could spin up an EC2 instance and just run the process manually there once.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give that a go

Comment: You can take a look at the AWS predefined ML docker images, you might want to extend on these images to reduce the build time as well - https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/containers/